# Can I make doxygen resolve @ref's to C++ standard library functions?

Tags: c++, doxygen, code-documentation

I sometimes want to refer, in my doxygen comments, to standard library constructs. I can do this with a HTML `<a>` element - but that's a lot of text to paste. I would much rather be able to write simply `{@ref std::string}`, and have doxygen know it needs to link to the cppreference.org [page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) for `std::string`.

I was thinking perhaps this could be possible if someone were to generate a doxygen tags file for the standard library (and even that might not work if tags file don't support arbitrary URLs). So, is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should have a Doxygen tag file and corresponding offline or online html files. So you can declare it in the Doxygen config file with this format:

```
TAGFILES = "/location/of/tagFile=http://onlineUrl Or /location/of/OfflineHtml"
```

To download these files, i found two below resources:

## Cppreference

I recommend this way. because of complete documentation of it.

### Online link

1. Download [web tag file](http://en.cppreference.com/w/File:cppreference-doxygen-web.tag.xml).
2. Set below in config file:

   ```
   TAGFILES += "location/of/cppreference-doxygen-web.tag.xml=http://en.cppreference.com/w/"
   ```

### Offline link

1. Download [html book](http://en.cppreference.com/w/File:html_book_20170409.zip) that is offline copy of the website.
2. Set below in config file:

   ```
   TAGFILES += "location/of/cppreference-doxygen-local.tag.xml=/location/of/html_book_*\reference\en"
   ```

[**More**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/Cppreference:Archives)

---

## GNU project

### Online link

1. Download [a tag file for the latest version](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/latest-doxygen/libstdc++.tag).
2. Set below in config file:

   ```
   TAGFILES = "/location/of/libstdc++.tag = http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/latest-doxygen"
   ```

### Offline link

1. Download [GCC 7.1 Standard C++ Library Reference Manual in HTML](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.1.0/libstdc++-api-html.tar.gz). other versions found [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/).
2. Set below in config file:

   ```
   TAGFILES = "/location/of/libstdc++.tag = /location/of/libstdc++-api-html"
   ```

[**More**](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.1.0/libstdc++-api-html.tar.gz)

Comment: Can you elaborate on what kind of tags you mean exactly, and how I can use them?

Comment: ... and will these tags point me online, or to local sources?

Comment: @einpoklum, it depends on your decision `Online link` or `Offline link`. look at [this link](https://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/external.html) about what is tags file in Doxygen.

Comment: Hi @ahoo this solution works fine when referring to classes (e.g. `@see std::vector`) but not when referring to functions (e.g. `@see std::distance`). I can see "distance" in the cppreference tag file, but Doxygen won't pick up the link. Am I supposed to use a different Doxygen syntax?

Comment: Shouldn't there be some separator at the end of each TAGFILES string addition?