# Are there Doxygen tag files for the C Standard Library (like those available for C++)?

Tags: c, doxygen

I wrote a small C library which I am currently trying to document using the Doxygen format. I am also using Doxygen to generate the documentation website for the library.

The types defined in my library show up as cross-links inside the documentation, which makes navigation very convenient. But the types from the C Standard Library (used, for instance, in my functions' signatures) don't have links, which is what this question is about.

My goal, if possible, would be to have types such at `size_t`, `char`, `int`, etc. contain links to an online documentation website such has [GCC, the GNU Compiler Collection](https://gcc.gnu.org/) or [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/). My understanding is that this can be achieved using the [TAGFILES](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_tagfiles) variable in the `Doxyfile`.

I stumbled upon [this interesting Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43099899/can-i-make-doxygen-resolve-refs-to-c-standard-library-functions) that explains how this can be done in C++, and which points to publicly available pre-built tag files, but I was wondering if such pre-built tag files would also exist for the C Standard Library types?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Doxygen does not maintain tag files. A quick search gave me (an old tag file for cpp: https://upload.cppreference.com/w/File:cppreference-doxygen-web.tag.xml) I thought there was also a tag file for C but I cannot find.

Comment: @albert Thanks for your comment. I found those files too for C++, but I haven't been able to find anything for C. I'll keep looking and I'll update this post if I find anything.

I may also try to write a simple one (tag file for C types) myself.